# SQL Division using 'not exists' in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
'committee' table

commname    profname
========================
commA       bill
commA       jack
commA       piper
commB       bill
commB       piper
```

and I am trying to find the professors who are in every committee that 'piper' is in
(answer should be piper and bill):

I have the following SQL division query but it's wrong and I can't figure out where the problem is (doesn't return bill, just piper):

```
select b.profname
from committee b
where not exists 

(select commname
from committee a
where profname = 'piper' and not exists 

(select commname
from committee
where a.profname=b.profname ))
```

Can somebody help me with this one?
Thanks,

Comment: http://www.techipost.com/2012/08/29/understanding-sql-query-of-division/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your innermost select isn't using anything from itself in its where clause, so it's always finding something for piper.  Try

```
select distinct b.profname from committee b
where not exists (
    select commname from committee a
    where a.profname = 'piper' and not exists  (
        select commname from committee c
        where c.profname=b.profname and c.commname=a.commname
    )
);
```