# Relational Division in SQL with SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-division

I'm trying to do a relational division on the following table (sorry for the Dutch phrasing) using [this document](http://users.abo.fi/soini/divisionEnglish.pdf) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330221/sql-division-using-not-exists-in-mysql).

```
    voedsel_id  dier_id
    1005        1006
    1004        1006
    1005        1005
    1005        1004
    1004        1004
    1001        1003
    1001        1002
    1001        1001
```

Which let to the following query for what I want to do.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dier_id
FROM Dieren_voedsel AS X
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT voedsel_id
    FROM Dieren_voedsel AS Y
    WHERE Y.dier_id = 1006 AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT voedsel_id
        FROM Dieren_voedsel AS Z
        WHERE X.voedsel_id = Z.voedsel_id AND Y.dier_id = Z.dier_id
    )
)
ORDER BY dier_id;
```

Which let to the following unexpected output.

```
dier_id
1004
1005
1006
```

I thought this division would output all the dier_id tuples that have exactly the same voedsel_id values as dier_id 1006. However, it includes dier_id 1005 which only has voedsel_id 1005 and dier_id 1006 has voedsel_id 1004 and 1005. I thought this would only return dier_id 1004 and 1006.
Is there something I did wrong or do I not know how a relational division works?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output would be dier_id 1004
 and 1006 since they have voedsel_id 1004 and 1005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your innermost subquery, you got the references to `X` and `Y` wrong:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dier_id
FROM Dieren_voedsel AS X
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM Dieren_voedsel AS Y
    WHERE Y.dier_id = 1006
      AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM Dieren_voedsel AS Z
        WHERE Z.dier_id = X.dier_id
          AND Z.voedsel_id = Y.voedsel_id
    )
)
ORDER BY dier_id;
```